# How to group by and merge these rows of spark dataframe's group

Tags: pandas, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, grouping

Suppose I have a table like this,

```
A  | B  |    C     | D  |  E  | F
x1 | 5  | 20200115 | 15 | 4.5 | 1
x1 | 10 | 20200825 | 15 | 5.6 | 19
x2 | 10 | 20200115 | 15 | 4.1 | 1
x2 | 10 | 20200430 | 15 | 9.1 | 1
```

I am looking to merge these rows on col `A` and produce a dataframe like this

```
A  | B  |    C     | D  |  E  | F
x1 | 15 | 20200825 | 15 | 5.6 | 19
x2 | 10 | 20200115 | 15 | 4.1 | 1
x2 | 10 | 20200430 | 15 | 9.1 | 1
```

Basically, if the sum of column B for the group in column A is equal to value of column D, then,

1. Column B's new value will be sum of column B
2. Column C, E, F will be picked up based on latest of column C (which is a date in YYYYmmDD)

Since for group X2, the above condition is not true (ie sum of column B is 20 is greater than column D 15), I want to retain both the records in the target

Assumption: In my data, column D for a given group will be the same (in this case it is 15)

I have looked at a bunch of grouping and windowing(partitioning) examples, but it looks to me that this is different and I am unable to narrow down on the route.

Can I pipe the grouped data to an UDF and do something?

PS: Building this in pyspark, it would be great if your examples can be in pyspark

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this-

**Use `sum` + `max` with windowing function**

```scala
df.show(false)
    df.printSchema()
    /**
      * +---+---+--------+---+---+---+
      * |A  |B  |C       |D  |E  |F  |
      * +---+---+--------+---+---+---+
      * |x1 |5  |20200115|15 |4.5|1  |
      * |x1 |10 |20200825|15 |5.6|19 |
      * |x2 |10 |20200115|15 |4.1|1  |
      * |x2 |10 |20200430|15 |9.1|1  |
      * +---+---+--------+---+---+---+
      *
      * root
      * |-- A: string (nullable = true)
      * |-- B: integer (nullable = true)
      * |-- C: integer (nullable = true)
      * |-- D: integer (nullable = true)
      * |-- E: double (nullable = true)
      * |-- F: integer (nullable = true)
      */

    val w = Window.partitionBy("A")
    df.withColumn("sum", sum("B").over(w))
      .withColumn("latestC", max("C").over(w))
      .withColumn("retain",
        when($"sum" === $"D", when($"latestC" === $"C", true).otherwise(false) )
          .otherwise(true) )
      .where($"retain" === true)
      .withColumn("B", when($"sum" === $"D", when($"latestC" === $"C", $"sum").otherwise($"B") )
        .otherwise($"B"))
      .show(false)

    /**
      * +---+---+--------+---+---+---+---+--------+------+
      * |A  |B  |C       |D  |E  |F  |sum|latestC |retain|
      * +---+---+--------+---+---+---+---+--------+------+
      * |x1 |15 |20200825|15 |5.6|19 |15 |20200825|true  |
      * |x2 |10 |20200115|15 |4.1|1  |20 |20200430|true  |
      * |x2 |10 |20200430|15 |9.1|1  |20 |20200430|true  |
      * +---+---+--------+---+---+---+---+--------+------+
      */
```

Answer (score 0):

in pyspark, I would do it like this :

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window as W

b = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"]
a = [
    ("x1", 5, "20200115", 15, 4.5, 1),
    ("x1", 10, "20200825", 15, 5.6, 19),
    ("x2", 10, "20200115", 15, 4.1, 1),
    ("x2", 10, "20200430", 15, 9.1, 1),
]

df = spark.createDataFrame(a, b)


df = df.withColumn("B_sum", F.sum("B").over(W.partitionBy("A")))

process_df = df.where("D >= B_Sum")
no_process_df = df.where("D < B_sum").drop("B_sum")


process_df = (
    process_df.withColumn(
        "rng", F.row_number().over(W.partitionBy("A").orderBy(F.col("C").desc()))
    )
    .where("rng=1")
    .select("A", F.col("B_sum").alias("B"), "C", "D", "E", "F",)
)

final_output = process_df.unionByName(no_process_df)
+---+---+--------+---+---+---+
|  A|  B|       C|  D|  E|  F|
+---+---+--------+---+---+---+
| x1| 15|20200825| 15|5.6| 19|
| x2| 10|20200115| 15|4.1|  1|
| x2| 10|20200430| 15|9.1|  1|
+---+---+--------+---+---+---+
```